# Using same Service multiple times

Tags: android, android-service

**SOLUTION**

Instead Services, I've used AlarmManager to solve the problem, and now, it works properly.

Thanks all!

---

I'm trying to use a service multiple times with different information.

An example of the code for the service that I've written is this:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int idArranque) {
        int time = intent.getExtras().getInt("timePhase");
        new CountDownTimer(time*1000,5000){    
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //Other code here....
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Finished: "+nameMedicine,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

From the Activity, each time that I call the Service, I pass a bundle with the time for the CountDown, but it not works correctly.. I'm assuming that the variables that are received in the service are overwritten by the last call to the service.

Is there any way to run each service in a different process to avoid the overwriting?

I've read this:

Link 1: [Use same service multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568527/use-same-service-multiple-times)

Link 2: [What happens if a Service is started multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019899/starting-a-service-multiple-times)

Link 3: [Multiple timers using same service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901498/multiple-timers-using-same-service)

But I don't know exactly what should I do.

---

### **UPDATE: DETAILED INFORMATION**

Service.java

```
public class timePhase extends Service {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    UsuariosSQLiteHelper usdbh;

    String nameMedicine;

    int time=0;
    int idPaciente;
    int idMedicamento;
    int count=0;
    Bundle b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }


    @Override

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int idArranque) {


        count++;
        int time = intent.getExtras().getInt("timePhase");
        idPaciente = intent.getExtras().getInt("idPatient");
        idMedicamento = intent.getExtras().getInt("idMedicine");
        banAccess(true);

        new CountDownTimer(time*1000,5000){

            //TODO: Toast no funciona
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }


            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                banAccess(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ha acabado el tiempo de espera de "+nameMedicine,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                count--;
                if(count==0) stopSelf();
            }
        }.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }



    @Override

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intencion) {
        return null;
    }

    public void banAccess(boolean status){

        usdbh =  new UsuariosSQLiteHelper(this, "DB", null, 1);
        usdbh.getWritableDatabase();
        db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();

        if(status) db.execSQL("Update pacienteCompuesto set validado=4 where id_paciente="+idPaciente+" and id_medicamento="+idMedicamento);
        else db.execSQL("Update pacienteCompuesto set validado=2 where id_paciente="+idPaciente+" and id_medicamento="+idMedicamento);
    }   
}
```

Each time that I click on a item on a ListView from an Activity, this service is launched.
I pass some variables to the service with a click on a item from the ListView through a Bundle, like the timer to the CountDown, and other important variables to alter the database on the finish of the CountDown.

If I click on one item of the ListView and the service is launched, it works ok.
If I click on one item of the ListView, and then I click on other item, the local variables of the service are of the second item... By this, the CountDown for the first item clicked not finish correctly (the instruction to modify the database is not executed with the values of the first item clicked, but yes with the values of the second clicked item).

Comment: what does *but it not works correctly..* mean ?

Comment: "I'm assuming that the variables that are received in the service are overwritten by the last call to the service" -- and what "variables" would those be? Please feel free to post the entire Java class, including indicating where and when you are stopping the service, so as not to be leaking it. "Is there any way to run each service in a different process to avoid the overwriting?" -- not really, and it is rather unlikely that this would be an appropriate solution to whatever your problem is.

Comment: The time of the count down is not the correct, and other instructions that I have in "onFinish()" method not are executed with the values that it should have... I'm assuming that the second call to the service are overwriting the values of the first call.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, I will publish the code in some hours, because I'm not at home right now. Thanks

Comment: I've published the code of the Service. Thanks!